# Texture on Sphere fuzzy after version upgrade

Tags: javascript, three.js

After upgrading from r67 to r86, our footballs are not very sexy anymore. Did anyone have similar issues in the past?

The code that used to render the spheres nicely, messes up the texture (and some lighting, but I can live with that) in version r86.

**The part that creates the spheres:**

```
const material = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({ map: texture, transparent: false });
material.alphaTest = 0.5;
const geometry = new THREE.SphereGeometry(radius, res, res);
const mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
```

[image]

[Fiddle using r86](https://jsfiddle.net/sL3wkuka/).

Comment: It looks like the UVs have changed (note how the text is morphed in the r86 version). Once the UVs are sorted, take a look at the different min filters/mag filters available: https://threejs.org/docs/#api/constants/Textures

Comment: @TheJim01 Added the minFilter, and it works. https://jsfiddle.net/sL3wkuka/2/ Thank you! Could you post your comment as an answer please?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In my comment, I suggested checking the UVs. My suggestion to try different min/mag filter values (http://threejs.org/docs/#api/constants/Textures) was more to correct the image quality, than the texture mapping its self.

What I didn't notice was that your texture was already spherical. The standard linear filter mapped the texture, well, linearly. The weighting/averaging of the linear filter caused the mapping to become compressed toward the top (and bottom, though it wasn't noticeable).

Setting `texture.minFilter = THREE.NearestFilter;` ditched the weighting/averaging of the texture coordinates, instead mapping to the nearest pixel, which was perfect because of your spherical texture.